# New leanaback's LeanbackTabLayout and LeanbackViewPager not focusing and changing tab with D-PAD controller

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

> I am using new leanback tab and viewpager. I am not able to change tab1 to tab2 with D-pad. Tabs changes from Tab1 to Tab2 when i reach to last item of rowfragment in Tab1. I am not able to jump to up from rowfragment item to Tab menu. I have mentioned code sample below. In developer video they are able switch tabs with d-pad. please answer this. thanks in advance :)

my build.gradle file :

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.leanback:leanback-tab:1.1.0-beta01"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

Fragment file:

```
class CollectionDemoFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var demoCollectionPagerAdapter : DemoCollectionPagerAdapter
private lateinit var viewPager : LeanbackViewPager
private lateinit var tab_layout : LeanbackTabLayout

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection_demo, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    demoCollectionPagerAdapter = DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager)
    viewPager.setKeyEventsEnabled(true)

    tab_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)
    viewPager.adapter = demoCollectionPagerAdapter
    tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
}
```

}

Fragment Xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".CollectionDemoFragment"
android:background="@android:color/white">


<androidx.leanback.tab.LeanbackViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.leanback.tab.LeanbackTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/lb_grey"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

</androidx.leanback.tab.LeanbackViewPager>
```

Adapter file:

```
class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    val fragment = DemoObjectFragment()
    fragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
        putInt(ARG_OBJECT, position + 1)
    }
    return fragment
}

override fun getCount(): Int = 4


override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
    return "OBJECT ${(position + 1)}"
}
```

}

I have gone through developer site and youtube video as well:
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/libraries#leanback-tabs-library

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOV6Ef9zDg0&t=1065s at 16:40 seconds

For more clarity i have Added image of screen. In image, I am not able to go from Selected item -> Tab2 -> Tab3. And now other hand, If i am at last item of Tab2 and then i click on D-pad right then and only it move to Tab3 and vice-versa first item at Tab3 then i can able to move to Tab2. Hope this clear my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syvb1.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like part of your layout is missing, but my best guess is that the LeanbackTabLayout doesn't handle being nested inside of the LeanbackViewPager. Try putting them at the same level:

```
<androidx.leanback.tab.LeanbackTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<androidx.leanback.tab.LeanbackViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Make sure that whatever is containing these views lays them out so that they don't overlap (e.g., just wrap them with a vertical LinearLayout for testing).

Comment: Hey @ian thanks for replying. I have edited my question,added new image and problem description in question. I have tried unfortunately it didn't work as expected. 
<LinearLayout> <tab.LeanbackTabLayout> </LeanbackViewPager></LinearLayout>...  Now in https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/libraries#leanback-tabs-library they have mentioned "Note that LeanbackViewPager is based on ViewPager, not ViewPager2.". So i followed this https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view viewpager guide they suggested include TabLayout and ViewPager. i don't understand.

Comment: Yeah, it should work like that. The Leanback* classes extend the non-leanback versions and add focus functionality but are otherwise the same. There's also a repository you can check out from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main/samples/SupportLeanbackDemos/ that contains an example of using these classes in case it helps troubleshooting.

Comment: Hey @lan i have cloned project SupportLeanbackDemos .. It is demo there of TabLayoutActivity. but this project is not building in android studio. project level gradle file  is missing and plugins { id("AndroidXPlugin") gives not found in any of sources 1)Gradle Core Plugins and 2)Plugin Repositories .. can you please tell me how can clone and run this project to see output.

Comment: Hey @lan G. Clifton can you please reply me.

Comment: The AndroidXPlugin is at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/androidx/build/AndroidXPlugin.kt but it might be easier to just copy the activity/fragment/layout files that you need into your existing project to test with. You might also want to try without setting setKeyEventsEnabled to see if it's interfering with the focus handling.

Comment: Hey @lan G. Clifton i have gone through code 2 times and pickup necessary classes, layout etc but it is not working as expected. Focus is still not moving  from Rowfragment item to Tab item. And second thing, i tried to comment setKeyEventsEnabled(true), Its working that It prevents go to next tab if we are at last item in previous tab. so 1 issue resolve. i don't think so i am making any copy paste mistake. I am running app in emulator. Could you go through my code if i upload my code on github.

Comment: hey hi @lan G. Clifton can you please reply me. i am really in help

Comment: Hi Malo. I tried but failed to fulfill my requirements. So instead I use activity and fragment. So on D-PAD buttons, let's say left and right, I replace the fragment, and also I set focus views accordingly. So this is how I achieved it. It took me a lot of time around 20 days to build a such custom page on TV